# Qt5 OpenCV3.4.5 LNK1105 cannot open opencv_world345d.obj

Tags: qt, opencv, qmake

I am building a Qt5 project with OpenCV3.4.5 in windows. The OpenCV is a prebuilt version with `opencv_world345.lib` and `opencv_world345dlib`. I create a `.pri` file for including opencv into the Qt project. Here below is for the opencv `.pri` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/include \
               C:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/include/opencv \
               C:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/include/opencv2
Debug: {
LIBS += lc:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/x64/vc14/lib/opencv_world345d
}
Release: {
LIBS += lc:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/x64/vc14/lib/opencv_world345
}
```

I also set `C:\opencv-3.4.5\prebuild\x64\vc14\bin` in the path of systems variables.

Building the project in debug mode gives the error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'lc:\opencv-3.4.5\prebuild\x64\vc14\lib\opencv_world345d.obj'`.

What causes the error? Do I miss something else in configuring opencv for Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run qmake since making your changes to the `.pri` file?

Normally I would have asked for clarification in the comments, but I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't have 50 reputation yet.

**EDIT:**

I found an old project of mine that I have OpenCV3.1.0 properly linked to. Here's what I have in my `.pro`

```
LIBS += -L*PATH TO OPEN CV*/OpenCV-3.1.0/lib


INCLUDEPATH += *PATH TO OPEN CV*/OpenCV-3.1.0/include
CONFIG(release, debug|release):{
    LIBS += \
        -lopencv_world310
}

CONFIG(debug, debug|release):{
    LIBS += \
        -lopencv_world310d
 }
```

Comment: Yes, every time I make changes to codes, I will run clean, qmake an rebuild the project

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but in all my pri files I separate my path names from my library names. So in your case it would be:

`Debug: {
LIBS += L"c:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/x64/vc14/lib" -lopencv_world345d
}
Release: {
LIBS += L"c:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/x64/vc14/lib" -lopencv_world345
}`

Comment: You are right!! It was my configurations for OpenCV that caused the linking error. The libraries were not recognized .

Answer (score 0):

Here below is the modified `.pri` file that works for me!

```
INCLUDEPATH += c:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/include
CONFIG(release, debug|release):{
    LIBS += -L"c:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/x64/vc14/lib" -lopencv_world345
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release):{
    LIBS += -L"c:/opencv-3.4.5/prebuild/x64/vc14/lib" -lopencv_world345d
}
```

The configurations by `Debug:{}` and `Release {}` do not work!